# Google Earth Engine App: adding two select boxes to a panel, second select box to show when user selects from first

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to create an earth engine app. Inside the app there is a `ui.Panel` having a `ui.select()` item. Basically I want that when a user selects from the the select item, a second select item to be shown.
In simple words from the first select option if a user selects a country, a second select option should show in the pane with states of that country selected.

The problem that I am facing is that when I select a country second or third time. The states select item is added to the panel that many times (on each click) like a loop.

[image: Select Province Repeated Three Times When I only want it once]

This is the script that I am using
https://code.earthengine.google.com/2767e5830f53ab9369a55008d911706f

```
// Designing a simple app in which user selects country from drop down first, then
// a second dropdown will show up with states/provinces of the country on map
var LSIB = ee.FeatureCollection('ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")');
var select_countries = LSIB.aggregate_array('country_na').sort().getInfo();
var select_country =  ui.Select({
  items: ['Pakistan','India'], //later change to select_countries 
  placeholder:'Select Country', 
  onChange:country_selected});



function country_selected(){
  var selected = select_country.get('value');
  var country = LSIB.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na',selected)); 
  // Refresh Existing Layers and display selected country on map
  Map.layers().reset();
  Map.clear();
  Map.centerObject(country);
  Map.addLayer(country,{color:'Red'},selected)
  Map.add(mainPanel)
  
  // Show states
  var provinces = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-mspkafg/assets/demo_provinces').aggregate_array('Name').sort().getInfo();
  var province_select = ui.Select({
  items: provinces, 
  placeholder:'Select Province', 
  onChange:province_function});
  
  function province_function(){
    var province_name = province_select.get('value');
    var provinces = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-mspkafg/assets/demo_provinces');
    var selected_province = provinces.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Name',province_name))
    Map.layers().reset();
    Map.clear();
    Map.centerObject(selected_province);
    Map.addLayer(selected_province,{color:'Green'},province_name)
    Map.add(mainPanel)
  }
  
  mainPanel.add(province_select)
  
}





// Create a panel and add select to it and display on map
var mainPanel = ui.Panel({
  style: {width: '300px', position:'bottom-right', height:'600px'}
});
var title = ui.Label({
  value: 'Demo',
  style: {'fontSize': '20px'}
});
mainPanel.add(title)
mainPanel.add(select_country)
Map.add(mainPanel)
```

Comment: Answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455728/google-earth-engine-adding-two-select-boxes-to-a-panel/455808#455808

Comment: Answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455728/google-earth-engine-adding-two-select-boxes-to-a-panel/455808#455808